# Testing Slider onSlidingComplete from @react-native-community/slider with jest and enzyme

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

Is there a way to test what is called when the react-native Slider is used with jest and enzyme? 
Here's a simplified version of how I attempted to do it:

```
    const mockOnSlidingComplete = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<Slider onSlidingComplete={mockOnSlidingComplete} />);

    const sliderElement = wrapper.find(Slider);
    sliderElement.simulate('valueChange');

    expect(mockOnSlidingComplete).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This failed, the event doesn't seem to match up with what the Slider is expecting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this since there is no way to simulate the UI/View sliding on unit tests.

```js
const mockOnSlidingComplete = jest.fn();
const wrapper = shallow(<Slider onSlidingComplete={mockOnSlidingComplete} />);

const sliderElement = wrapper.find(Slider);
sliderElement.props.onSlidingComplete()

expect(mockOnSlidingComplete).toHaveBeenCalled();
```